# Open View Controller programmatically and not using a Seque

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I know that this is a really simple question but I am getting nowhere.

I have a storyboard and all the view controllers are opened using segues which is fine, but I would like to open one of them using code when the button is pressed.

What is the line for opening the view controller called `ViewControllerMonitorMenu` when the `testSliders` button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)testSliders:(id)sender
{

}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have finally got it. Thanks for everyone's help:

```
ViewControllerMonitorMenu *monitorMenuViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerMonitorMenu"];
[self presentViewController:monitorMenuViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: Have you named your view in the storyboard?

Answer (score 6):

This code programatically created **object** of `ViewControllerMonitorMenu` and also you can go on it.

```
- (IBAction)testSliders:(id)sender 
    {
       ViewControllerMonitorMenu * object = [[ViewControllerMonitorMenu alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:object animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```

Comment: Sorry - and thanks for your help - but I don't follow. I have copied your code and it does not recognise MYViewController - suggesting it should be UIViewController. Also am I right to be using the StoryBoardID?

Comment: use ViewControllerMonitorMenu....check my edited

Comment: Thanks - should the word object be changed to crc? I have done this and screen just goes black now.

Comment: check my edited...;) it is only variable your can give name as your want ...nothing more :)+1 for you...to good starting keep it up

Comment: Done this but the screen just goes black. Is it the storyboardID I use to refer to the View Controller? Sorry - I know this is easy.

Comment: in put     self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; in viewDidLoad method of your ViewControllerMonitorMenu

Comment: ? The View Controller called ViewControllerMonitorMenu is already set up with loads on it. What I mean your code does not seem to open it and screen just goes blank. Again, am I right to use StoryboardID to refer to the view controller?

Comment: @RichardGriffiths-screen is open but you need to change only background color of view of ViewControllerMonitorMenu.

Comment: OK - thanks for trying. The screen goes red but I don't want a red screen - I want to see the view controller with everything on it.

Comment: I have used but the background turns black