# Switching between views in iOS app

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I have a slide out menu in my app and each of the things in the menu goes to the respective pages.

Basically, when I tap "graph section" on the dashboard, I want it to go to the graph page without the Dashboard back button.

I've tried doing this with a modal segue but this provides a back button which means I can't access the menu on this page.

Anyone know how to do this?

[image: Linked Graph Page]

[image: Graphs Page]

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. Please think with the fact that no one on this site, other than you, knows what your app looks like or how it is supposed to function. Lay out all of the information regarding it before asking the questions. For instance, what is "Dashboard" and what are the "graphs", what is the "graph page"?

Comment: Image two is what I want when I tap "graph section". Image one is what it currently transitions to.

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. I still don't know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure whether this answers it but have a look at:

[Open View Controller programmatically and not using a Seque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686233/open-view-controller-programmatically-and-not-using-a-seque/15687190#15687190)

Comment: It moves to the correct view but the whole header section is not there. The title and the menu button isn't there.

Comment: I can't figure out what your three images are. Does image 1 show what happens when you press Graph Section on image 3? And image 2 what should appear when you press Live View Graph on image 1? It very confusing.

Comment: I want it to look like image two when I jump to the graphs page but image one is what I get.

Comment: Also, please read the question and what I want before saying it's confusing. It's not that complicated.

Comment: @user2900772, it isn't that complicated to you because you wrote the app and you know everything about it. We know nothing about it, so using references that are not defined make it confusing.

Comment: All I want is a transition to what is shown in image two. I want this transition to happen when "graph section" in the dashboard image is tapped. It's just a big button right now. When I tap anywhere in the top half of the screen I want it to transition to the view shown in image two. I've tried but I get to what is shown in image one instead.

Comment: So image 3 is the first view and you want it to go to image 2 but it goes to image 1 instead. Is that right?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: Yep, I'm using a storyboard for the view controllers and I used a modal segue to connect "Graph Section" button to the graphs view.

Comment: I am a little confused - if they are separate view controllers created on the storyboard then you should be able to delete the navigation controller on your image 1 and make it look like image 2. You can use a segue or a programatic method for navigating between the views. No?

Comment: I've already tried doing it with a segue and also programatically. Same result for both. I think it's because of the slide out menu that I'm using it. Here's the link to the github repo: https://github.com/andreamazz/SlideOutNavigation

Guess I need some help understanding how this menu switches between views when an option is selected in the menu.

Comment: I can't help but think you are over complicating what you want to do. The button can link to another view using a segue (or programatically)  without all this. You do not want all the fancy stuff so why add it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you Use navigation controller.Once you hide the navigation controller for that particular page with `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];` and add UIButton and write it's action